# Microsoft .NET security model

Tags: .net

I am looking for informations about the security model of Microsoft .NET
If you could explain me how it is design, or give me links to understand it, it would be very kind of you !

Thanks.

Comment: This is topic that a book would be best for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an older book but I still find it an excellent reference

[.Net Security ( Jason Bock, Tom Fischer, Nathan Smith , Pete Stromquist )](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590590538)

I've heard good things about this one too: [Programming .NET Security by Adam Freeman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596004427)